# Using javascript inside ListView?

Tags: c#, javascript, listview

I have a javascript to show an slideshow for my banners. I have a ListView which loads my banners from database. I don't have an idea to mix these together and let javascript loads banners from database.
This is my JavaScript:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var i = 1;
        function fun() {
            var banner = new array();
            banner[0] = '1.jpg';
            banner[1] = '2.jpg';
            banner[2] = '3.jpg';
            banner[3] = '4.jpg';
            i++;
            document.getElementById("img1").src = "slide/" + banner[i] + ".jpg";
            if (i == 3) //here 2 is number of images i want to display in the slide show
            { i = 0; }
        }
        setInterval("fun()", 4000);
</script>
```

This is my listView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvShowProducts" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
         <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <%# Eval("Filename")%>            
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Filename inside the listView should be placed in JavaScript Array. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable i is not scoped. Please move it inside the function. Arrays in JavaScript don't need to be explicitly created with the Array constructor. If you'd like to have a global counter, use document.body. Here's the cleaned up JavaScript code:

```
function fun(){
  if (!document.body.bannerindex) document.body.bannerindex=0;
  else document.body.bannerindex++;

  //set a clipping value
  if (document.body.bannerindex==3) document.body.bannerindex=0;

  //declare the array
  var banner=['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg'];

  //in your example, you duplicated ".jpg". it's fixed here
  document.getElementById('image1').src='slide/'+banner[document.body.bannerindex];

}

//do not write "fun()". setInterval takes a pointer to the function, not the return value of it!
setInterval(fun,4000);
```

Now about how you can call this function. If you need a trigger, create a button, and add an onclick event. If you want the entire page to load, call setInterval in either the footer, or window.onload event.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, but that's not the point! I want that image name loaded from a listview or something else. the image names are in the database. how to do that?

Comment: I'm sure there are elegant .NET ways to do this. But what I did before was to have a data list that's bound to the database, and display it in a hidden div. Then use JavaScript to dynamically create an array of image files. I assume you know how to print out a list of labels from the database? Give the hidden div an ID, say, "images". Then you can do files=document.getElementById('images').getElementsByTagName('div'); Make sure each label is in a div too.